# how to disable zoomIn/zoomOut button in certain zoomlevel eg: respectively zoomlevel 18 and zoomlevel 0

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, arcgis-runtime

I am tryng to develop a **naviagtion map system** using *ArcGIS Runtime for Java*, and FXML files for the view part. I am currently facing zoomButtons disabling: in some `zoomlevel` examples, the `zoomIn` button should be disabled at `zoomlevel = 18` and `zoomout` should be disabled at `zoomlevel = 0`. Now I am stuck while trying to disable those buttons at several zoom levels. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? You can find the attached code below.

I have already developped the `zoomIn` and `zoomOut` methods and they are working properly.

```
//ZoomIn Function is created 
public void zoomInFunction() {
    Viewpoint current = mapView.getCurrentViewpoint(Viewpoint.Type.CENTER_AND_SCALE);
    Viewpoint zoomedIn = new Viewpoint((Point) current.getTargetGeometry(), current.getTargetScale() / 2.0);
    mapView.setViewpointAsync(zoomedIn);
}

//ZoomOut Function is created
public void zoomOutFunction() {
    Viewpoint current = mapView.getCurrentViewpoint(Viewpoint.Type.CENTER_AND_SCALE);
    Viewpoint zoomedOut = new Viewpoint((Point) current.getTargetGeometry(), current.getTargetScale() * 2.0);
    mapView.setViewpointAsync(zoomedOut);
}

// Create action event for ZoomIn Function
public void zoomInAction(ActionEvent event) {
    map.zoomInFunction();  
}

// Create action event for ZoomOut Function
public void zoomOutAction(ActionEvent event) {
    map.zoomOutFunction();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a property (`zoomLevel`) and bind the `disableProperty` of the buttons to the zoomLevel property when it goes above or below certain maximum and minimum values.

*Zoom between min and max*

[image: zoom between min and max]

*Zoomed out*

[image: zoomed out]

*Zoomed in*

[image: zoomed in]

Implementation is pretty straightforward.  A sample app is provided below to demonstrate the concepts involved.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BoundedZoom extends Application {

    private static final int MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL = 1;
    private static final int MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL = 5;
    private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL = 3;

    private IntegerProperty zoomLevel = new SimpleIntegerProperty(DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL);

    public int getZoomLevel() {
        return zoomLevel.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty zoomLevelProperty() {
        return zoomLevel;
    }

    public void setZoomLevel(int zoomLevel) {
        this.zoomLevel.set(zoomLevel);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button zoomIn = new Button("Zoom In");
        zoomIn.setOnAction(event -> setZoomLevel(getZoomLevel() + 1));
        zoomIn.setDisable(getZoomLevel() >= MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL);
        zoomIn.disableProperty().bind(zoomLevel.greaterThanOrEqualTo(MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL));

        Button zoomOut = new Button("Zoom Out");
        zoomOut.setOnAction(event -> setZoomLevel(getZoomLevel() - 1));
        zoomOut.setDisable(getZoomLevel() <= MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL);
        zoomOut.disableProperty().bind(zoomLevel.lessThanOrEqualTo(MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL));

        Label zoomLevelDescLabel = new Label("Zoom level (min " + MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL + ", max " + MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL + "): ");
        Label zoomLevelValueLabel = new Label("" + getZoomLevel());
        zoomLevelValueLabel.textProperty().bind(zoomLevel.asString());

        Pane zoomLevelDisplay = new HBox(10, zoomLevelDescLabel, zoomLevelValueLabel);
        Pane controlPane = new HBox(10, zoomIn, zoomOut);

        Pane layout = new VBox(10, zoomLevelDisplay, controlPane);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```